Error when launching the Epic game Launcher
I have created an account and downloaded the app. When I open the launcher it works and it says that it is searching for an update installation. Once this is finished, the app crashes and opens again. It once again, repeats the installation and crashes again, until I force the closing of the app.
I have tried to follow the tips that epic games provides, such as erasing the cache.
Moreover, even tough I had enough space, I have tried to liberate more.
Nothing works, can somebody help me?
